# Need help fixing error IOUContractNull attachments cannot be found

Tags: corda

I'm currently working on Corda's [Hello World tutorial pt.2](https://docs.corda.net/tut-two-party-introduction.html) but I am encountering an error that I don't know how to fix. Whenever I try to create an `IOUFlow` between two nodes from the Corda shell:

```
>>> start IOUFlow iouValue: 99, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
```

I get an error:

> Cannot find contract attachments for com.template.IOUContractNull.

Any help in fixing this?

Comment: how people will know, that how your code looks like? and so does the problem? show your code trials and errors? add some context to your post. please read [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

This error normally happens when your contract ID is not synced with your package name.

You should check your contract ID at the IOUContract file.